# Angularjs.copy does not save to db?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a credit card form with a btn that pulls the address from the database (Use home address), its working in the sense that it shows up inside of the textfield but when saving the form, this textfield turns up empty in the db. Anyone got any feedback?

```
<div class="row clearfix">
 <div class="col-md-12 column">
  <div class="form-group">
   <button href="" ng-click="getAddress(user)" value="Show" class="btn btn-general btn-xs">Use Home Address</button>
   <input type="text" data-vkeysinput="" class="form-control" value="{{copyAddress}}"/>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>


$scope.getAddress = function(user) {
  $scope.copyAddress= angular.copy(user.user_address.address_1);
};
```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy no magic here. you'll need to do a remote request to your backend.

Answer (score 1):

`angular.copy` have absolutely nothing to do with a database.

*AngularJS* can't even talk to a database - you need some kind of backend to support that.

Comment: There is a Save btn that submits the whole form (including the credit card form) and binds it to the db (json), so whatever I write into the form gets saved in the db, all that is working fine. But for some reason then I have the address pulled in with angularjs.copy it does not recognize that as a valid input.

Comment: There is no way your *Angular* application is putting anything into your database. It's submitting it to a backend that puts it in the database.

If it's not recognizing it as valid input, it's most likely a problem in your backend